# UITableViewCell display wrong content

Tags: objective-c

It is base on UITableViewController.
My Table consists of two sections,

(1) The frist section display object from array, the label text is black and have detail able text

(2) The second section has a single row, which use to get into new ViewController to add more object

The initial view is correct, however, when I try to add more object to the array and reload data, the table display the wrong content for wrong cell.

So can anyone tell me where or what I did wrong?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  if (section == 0) return self.addItems.count;
  else return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Add Items List";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                  reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
  }

  if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    Item *item = [self.addItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08i", item.identifier.intValue];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.detailDescription;
  }
  else {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Create Item";
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [tableView tintColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
  }

  return cell;
}

- (void)unwindToAddItemsViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
  CreateItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
  [self.addItems addObjectsFromArray:source.createItems];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: What is the usage of this method ' unwindToAddItemsViewController ' ?

Comment: Cells will be reused, if you are planning to use the same cell for both sections have a reset method in a cell which will reset all the views in cell to its original state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I correct if I guess that "wrong content" means the textLabel of the cells in your first section have the wrong color?

That's because you don't set the textColor of the textLabel in your `section == 0` code path. Cells are reused, so if you use the same reuse identifier you have to set the attributes in all your code paths. The cell from section 1 keeps the textColor for the label once it was set. So if that cell is reused as a section 0 cell you have to change it back to the value you want in that section.

And since you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` to dequeue a cell you can remove the `if (!cell)` part. That method never returns nil.

Your code should look like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Add Items List";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    Item *item = [self.addItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08i", item.identifier.intValue];

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // NEW

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.detailDescription;
  }
  else {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Create Item";
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [tableView tintColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
  }
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solve my problem. So that is how things work. Now I understand more about this dequeueReusable things!. But it still has a problem.

By displaying "wrong content", I mean it has wrong color, and and there is not any subtitle showing until I click on it. Now the color is right, but the subtitle still not showing until I click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that solve my problem. So that is how things work. Now I understand more about this dequeueReusable things!.

But it still has a problem. By displaying "wrong content", I mean it has wrong color, and and there is not any subtitle showing until I click on it. There is a space for subtitle under title, but it is blank, until i click on it.

Now the color is right, but the subtitle still not showing until I click on it.